# Sub Menus will not work

Tags: menus

I am desperately needing help. I have done everything to my knowledge to try to get my sub menus back on my website. I installed a meta slider plugin to get a slider on my homepage. It worked well and then after that, my sub menus stopped working! I then deactivated the plugin, thinking that is what caused it, and the sub menus still did not show up on my website. 
Not sure if I am missing code or what, but I will appreciate any help I can get. 
I also have the hemmingway theme, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: http://www.fayettecofarmbureau.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your sub menus are hidden behind your header wrapper because the overflow is set to hidden.

[image]

So a quick fix would be to go to `Admin > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS` and paste in the following CSS.  This will allow the overflow content to be visible.

```
.header-cover {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Note: I have no idea what you changed to cause this or if this has any adverse effects to your site so be sure to test it out.